# How to get notification when download count beyond some numbers?

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, alert, logging, notifications

We can create alerts when some event triggered. But I want to get notification by email when users trying to download more than 10 documents in a day. Any possibilities? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do this myself, but I have seen a couple of screens in the menu where 'audit' is mentioned.

I'm using Sharepoint 2013.  Here's one menu: Site Settings>Configure Audit Settings.

Another one is 'View Audit Reports', also accessible via Site Settings.  Perhaps newly activated audit configurations show up as reports in here.

Though for SPO - see this [MS link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3d3f1d58-a738-4c29-bd13-fdec53cecf94/monitoring-download-activity-on-sharepoint-online-office365?forum=onlineservicessharepoint); it depends whether you are using cloud or on-premises Sharepoint.  Although one of the Answers also mentions using the [Audit Logs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).